# Применение полиморфизма

Tags: php

Интересует пример полиморфизма, с кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class Abastact 
{
    public function do();
}

class Class1 extends Abastact
{
    public function do()
    {
        echo 'class1';
    }
}

class Class2 extends Abastact
{
    public function do()
    {
        echo 'class2';
    }
}
```

Смысл полиморфизма в том что, независимо от того какой объект получаешь (`Class1` или `Class2`), у него точно будет интерфейс класса `Abastact`. Такое поведение полезно когда объект получается динамически.